# Eclipse, How to add all dependencies of one project to another

Tags: eclipse, dependencies

I have a project in Eclipse which I built using Maven and it has hundreds of JARs as reference libraries. Is there a way to include all these reference libraries to another project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the original project involved Maven dependencies, there are two ways of doing this.

### - Maven

To accomplish this in Maven style refer to this question. [How to add "Maven Managed Dependencies" library in build path eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859825/how-to-add-maven-managed-dependencies-library-in-build-path-eclipse)

### - Adding a project as dependency

The more simpler way of doing this (for beginners and testers), is to just include the original project as a dependency to the new project.

- In your original project, travel to Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export.
  Select all the dependencies that you want for your new project.
- In your new project, travel to Properties > Java Build Path > Projects. Now add the original project.