# How to paste all dependencies of one project to another in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, dependencies

I am trying to add a project (FMutAnalysisV2) as dependency to another project (Barbecue) for testing purpose (so I don't want to use jar files nor maven, just an eclipse solution). I followed the advice given on  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327361/eclipse-how-to-add-all-dependencies-of-one-project-to-another) and I am able to reference the classes of the project FMutAnalysisV2 in the project Barbecue. But all the dependencies of the project FMutAnalysisV2 aren't available in the project Barbecue, and therefore I receive a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, even with the solution proposed in the above mentioned post.

Does anyone have a clue to what iswrong with my setup? Both projects use the same JDK (1.8.0_121) and I am working with Eclipse Neon2 (4.6.2).

FMutAnalysisV2 is a maven project whit the "Order & Export" as followed:
[image]

Barbecue is a simple eclipse project with the JavaBuildPath > Projects as followed:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some try and error I finally got a solution. I had to go to Barbecue(ProjectB) > Properties > Project References > check FMutAnalysisV2 (ProjectA), then it worked.[image]