# Appcompat does not work

Tags: android

I am trying to use appcompat in my application. I have done everything according to the instructions. But when I add android-support-v7-appcompat as a library in my proect, I have an error like so:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 
'C:\Android\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\bin\
android-support-v7-appcompat.jar'
  testActionBar     Build path  Build Path Problem
```

what am I not doing right?

Comment: you need to reference appcompat properly in your android project

Comment: follow http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: I suppose library shouldn't even be in the bin folder as this folder get re-generated every now and then...just a thought

Answer (score 9):

- delete `appcompat.jar` and `v4-support.jar` from `libs` folder
- clean ur project

  [How to add android-support-v7-appcompat as a library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)
- import `android-support-v7-appcompat` in eclipse as a **library project** and
  **check copy into workspace**
- add `android-support-v7-appcompat` as library in ur project
- `right click on ur project` -----> `properties` ------>`android`
  ------> `add`

[image: how to add v-7 as library]

- **clean ur project**

I think this will help u

Comment: I did everything exactly, and received error when do "right click on ur project -----> properties ------>android ------> add"

Answer (score 5):

Before creating the project, run eclipse as Administrator so that it creates the jar in the location that it is referencing to.

Right click the eclipse icon and select the option"Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 2):

Just do the following steps

1. appcompat_v7_nn right click build project;
2. click to your project, project clean

Answer (score 0):

Delete jar library from every directory you add. Then you need to add appcompat as a dependency. If you use Android Studio, you need to do as following:

add this

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'`

into your gradle dependencies and after that, Build -> Rebuild Project.

Comment: How I can do it in eclipse?

Comment: Check this out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859825/how-to-add-maven-managed-dependencies-library-in-build-path-eclipse .
And if you are a beginner, i suggest you to learn android on Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

With "compatibility" files problems you can try to delete / or rename for security any appcompat "project" in eclipse and create a new project using a compatibility mode (different target and "required" SDK values, equals to your version needs), it will generate a new appcompat project, remember to link your existing project to this appcompat project and check your lib for no duplicate compat. jar.