# R file, styles.xml and android.graphics.Typeface

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I installed Luna in linux and imported my projects from juno/kepler (not sure now) and I'm getting the following errors

My ***R*** file dissapeared and I assumed it's due to an xml parsing error.

I am getting this message whenever opening any *.xml related to layouts:

`parseSdkContent failed
Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface` x 2 (multiple errors occurred)

I erased **.android** inside /home as an answer suggested but the error persists.

I'm running **Android 2.2** in my project (I can see the library is included) although `Right Click -> Project Properties -> Android -> Has Android 2.2, Android 4.4W and Android L (Preview)` **ALL** unchecked and the "apply" button doesn't work when I close the window (selecting android 2.2).

Whenever I open **Android SDK Manager** I get this message

`parseSdkContent failed
Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface`

On my styles.xml file I have the following error:

`error => <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>`

`error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 
 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.`

and

`error => <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>`

`error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 
 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.`

I checked for updates in the **android sdk manager** and found none, having installed:

- **TOOLS**:
- Android SDK tools
- Android SDK Platform-tools
- Android SDK Build-tools
- **ANDROID L API 20, L PREVIEW**:
- SDK Platform Android L Preview
- Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image
- Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image
- **ANDROID 4.4W API 20**:
- SDK Platform
- Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image
- Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image
- **ANDROID 2.2 API 8**:
- SDK Platform
- Android Support Library

And here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.diverse.just"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.diverse.just.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
              <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.diverse.just.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is any error in `res` folder `R` file is not generated. You have errors in `styles` folders because `android:Theme.Holo.Light` and `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` are not available for `api-8(android 2.2)`

1. Right click on your project.
2. Go to properties.
3. Select `Android` option from left panel.
4. Check any android `platform 3.0 or above`.
5. Clean your project.

**EDIT :**

- You can use `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar` this theme.
- `Or` Import [Appcompat from sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229189/appcompat-does-not-work/21229781#21229781) and use `appcompat's` theme.
- `Or` Use [Holo Everywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)

Comment: how can I check actual themes available (default) for 2.2 then?