# How to add Android Support v7 libraries in eclipse?

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

How do I add Android Support v7 libraries in eclipse? For example how do I add CardView to an eclipse android project?

Note: This was a self answer question, so no need to waste your time making an answer. Of course, if you have anything to add, please do.

Comment: u can take a look at [this SO question too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229189/appcompat-does-not-work/21229781#21229781)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

I know this looks like a lot of steps, but in reality it's just very broken down and only takes two minutes

To add a Support Library with resources (such as v7 cardview) to your application project using Eclipse:

Create a library project based on the support library code:

- Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Library using the SDK Manager.
- Create a library project and ensure the required JAR files are included in the project's build path:
- Select **File > Import**.
- Select **Existing Android Code Into Workspace** and click Next.
- Browse to the SDK installation directory and then to the Support Library folder. For example, if you are adding the `cardview` project, browse to `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/cardview/`.
- Click Finish to import the project. For the v7 cardview project, you should now see a new project titled `android-support-v7-cardview`.
- In the new library project, expand the `libs/` folder, right-click each `.jar` file and select **Build Path > Add to Build Path**. For example, when creating the v7 cardview project, add the `android-support-v7-cardview.jar` file to the build path. (Depending on your setup, Eclipse may have done this four you already.)
- Right-click the library project folder and select **Build Path > Configure Build Path**.
- In the **Order and Export** tab, check the `.jar` files you just added to the build path, so they are available to projects that depend on this library project. For example, the cardview project requires you to export the `android-support-v7-cardview.jar` file. (Depending on your setup, Eclipse may have done this four you already.)
- Uncheck **Android Dependencies**.
- Click **OK** (or **Apply and Close**) to complete the changes.

You now have a library project for your selected Support Library that you can use with one or more application projects.

Now add the library to your application project:

- In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select **Properties**.
- In the category panel on the left side of the dialog, select **Android**.
- In the **Library** pane, click the **Add** button.
- Select the library project and click **OK**. For example, the appcompat project should be listed as `android-support-v7-cardview`.
- In the properties window, click **OK** (or **Apply and Close**).

For some libraries, you will get error messages such as

> No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'. styles_base.xml/appcompat_v7/res/values-v21

If that happens, record the highest API level you are seeing in those error messages (v21 in the example above). Then, in the properties of your library project, go to **Android** and set the target API to that level (or a higher one), then clean your projects.

Comment: The procedure doesn't work for newly packaged compat libraries. Any ideas except of extracting sources and trying to build Eclipse projects for them?

Comment: @DmitriyR maybe add the source files directly to your project?

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me. (Using the same CardView example from above)

1. Import CardView into the workspace:

   1. Click on **File**, then click on **Import**.
   2. Expand the **Android** folder, and select **Existing Android Code into Workspace**, then click on **Next >**.
   3. Click on **Browse** beside the Root Directory text input, and select the **CardView project folder** in `(Android SDK Install Location) > extras > android > support > v7 > cardview`
2. Right click the CardView project, click **Properties**, then select **Android** from the list on the left.
3. Check **Is Library** checkbox, and click **Apply**.
4. In your project, right click and click on **Properties**, then select **Android** from the list on the left, and click **Add**.
5. Your imported CardView project will be listed there. Select the **CardView project**, then click **OK**, and click **Apply**.

Now the library is imported.

PS: I tried I'm_With_Stupid's answer, and while trying to add the library project to my project, it was not listed there.
I did not have to uncheck Android Dependencies, etc. It might work in some other situation, I guess.

Comment: this is actually the easiest solution, if you select the entire support folder you can then check/uncheck the things that you want and you get a library project with exactly those things