# I want Material Design in Pre 5.0 device in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, material-design

I am have made an app and now i am trying to implement material design in my app.
Problem is that i have made this app in eclipse. I have downloaded Android Studio too but its not familiar and i am use too eclipse.

My question is how to add material design theme in device lower than 5.0. I have currently 4.3 on my Galaxy S3.

Can any one please guide me on how to achieve material design in eclipse version 20140702

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

First of all add appcompat_v7 support library in your project. Then use following application style:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
    ......
</application>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Here is my demo project for Material Design below 5.0 with Toolbar and Recycler view but its in Android Studio, you can use for reference:
[MaterialDesign_Part1](https://github.com/rahulparihar09/MaterialDesign_Part1)

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: @Mustakim0077 Accept the ans if u find it useful

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Support Material Design Library that were released 2 weeks ago.

Official documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html

Here are the features of libs:

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

And here to install lib with eclipse:

[How to add Android Support v7 libraries in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878803/how-to-add-android-support-v7-libraries-in-eclipse)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the references