# How to Import Android Design Library in eclipse?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design

I updated My Android Support Library Version to 23.1.1?.. But Can't able to find and Import design Library?..

Comment: do you restarted your eclipse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I attach the Android Support Library source in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543225/how-do-i-attach-the-android-support-library-source-in-eclipse)

Comment: S.. I restarted My Eclipse.. My Question is I want to add Floating Lables and Snackbar In My Project.. But I can't find Design Lib after Updated Android Support Lib 23.1.1

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26878804/2703209

Answer (score 0):

In order to use android design support library, try importing it from your SDK library.
It should be in `your_SDK_path/extras/android/support` in the folder you can find `design`, import it as a project in your eclipse and set is as `is Library`.

Just Refresh, Clean and Build.

Comment: In Version 23.1.1 i didn't find support/design

Answer (score 0):

You can find your library here inside your SDK

```
.../sdk/extras/android/support/design/libs
```

So, import from that, you will get your library.