# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'theme' in package in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am bit amateur in the android programming and I have trying to implement a project in eclipse. I have already added up the android-support-v7-appcompat.jar as the library. I am getting the error in my toolbar.xml as

**error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'theme' in package 'com.example.goon'**

Here is my toolbar.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

I am bit confused with what should be done and I would be glad if anyone could help me with the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: move to android studio and gradle thats all the help ill give you

Comment: Cant I continue it on eclipse? isnt ther a way out in eclipse?

Comment: There is, what are you using to build? gradle or something else?

Comment: No, I have not been using gradle. Should i need to integrate gradle with that ?

Comment: then whats your build system? ant?

Comment: The support v7 lib has its own resources and in order to add that to eclipse you need to follow this see this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26878804/4128945

Comment: Okay. I will work on the following thing. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support v7 lib has its own resources and in order to add that to eclipse you need to follow this

From: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

I know this looks like a lot of steps, but in reality it's just very broken down and only takes two minutes

Adding libraries with resources
To add a Support Library with resources (such as v7 cardview) to your application project:

Using Eclipse

Create a library project based on the support library code:

- Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Library using the SDK Manager.
- Create a library project and ensure the required JAR files are included in the project's build path:
- Select File > Import.
- Select Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.
- Browse to the SDK installation directory and then to the Support Library folder. For example, if you are adding the cardview project, browse to /extras/android/support/v7/cardview/.
- Click Finish to import the project. For the v7 cardview project, you should now see a new project titled android-support-v7-cardview.
- In the new library project, expand the libs/ folder, right-click each .jar file and select Build
- Path > Add to Build Path. For example, when creating the the v7 cardview project, add the android-support-v7-cardview.jar file to the build path.
- Right-click the library project folder and select Build Path > Configure Build Path.
- In the Order and Export tab, check the .jar files you just added to the build path, so they are available to projects that depend on this library project. For example, the cardview project requires you to export the android-support-v7-cardview.jar file.
- Uncheck Android Dependencies.
- Click OK to complete the changes.
- You now have a library project for your selected Support Library that you can use with one or more application projects.
- Add the library to your application project:
- In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select Properties.
- In the category panel on the left side of the dialog, select Android.
- In the Library pane, click the Add button.
- Select the library project and click OK. For example, the appcompat project should be listed as android-support-v7-cardview.
- In the properties window, click OK.

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26878804/4128945)

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the appcompat is a **library with own resources** and **it is not enough to import the jar** in your project.

First of all please **consider to switch to Android Studio**.
It would be very easy to use the library. Just add a dependency in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    // Support Libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

If you want to use **Eclipse** please first read this [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/tools/help/adt.html)

> **Important: Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse has ended, per our announcement.** You should migrate your app development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible. For more information on transitioning to Android Studio, see Migrating from Eclipse ADT.

In any case you can find all the release of the support libraries library in this folder:

```
sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/
```

Here you can check all version.
In the folders you will find the `aar` file of the support libraries.
Inside you can check the `classes.jar` file,the res folder and the `AndroidManifest` file.

- Create a project in your workspace
- Unzip the AAR into some directory.
- Copy the `AndroidManifest.xml`, the `res`, and `assets` folders from the AAR into your project.
- Create a `libs` directory in your project and copy into it the `classes.jar`
- Add the dependency.
- Use the SDK 23 to compile
- Mark the project as a library

The AppCompat library has the support-v4.jar and the support-annotations-23.x.X.jar as dependencies.