# Android: chrome custom tab on eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, chrome-custom-tabs

How can i add chrome custom tab to android project on eclipse 
here is a [document](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)  descries add it to android studio but i have no time to switch to android studio is their any way to import it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the custom tabs support library to your project on Eclipse. It's the same steps you would follow for any other support library on Android. Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) that explains how to do it.

You can also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878803/how-to-add-android-support-v7-libraries-in-eclipse) StackOverflow question about setting up support libraries v7.