# import appcompat v7 in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, import, android-appcompat

I set up Android SDK in eclipse, and then have made a project.
But I met some error like followings

---

### error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'

Someone recommends to import the "android-support-v7-appcompat" in "android-sdk/extras/android/support/"

But I cann't fine the directory and file.
Instead, I found the file "appcompat-v7-24.0.0" in "C:\Users\user\android-sdks\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\24.0.0".

I tried to import this file, but Import window of eclipse doesn't display any project.
So I can't solve this problem.

How I can solve this problem? Help me...

Comment: Why are you using Eclipse and not Android Studio? It's official IDE provided by Google. Eclipse doesn't have more support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Android Support v7 libraries in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878803/how-to-add-android-support-v7-libraries-in-eclipse)

Comment: I have the same problem! any solutions?