# Eclipse can't import Appcompat-v7

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-appcompat

My Eclipse having this error:

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'

I know that I have to add the appcompatv7 to my eclipse and I know how to theoretically do this, but this doesn't work. I found another guy with the same problem but nobody answered him:

[import appcompat v7 in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136209/import-appcompat-v7-in-eclipse)

I have a appcompat-v7 folder with lots of other folders inside with names like 25.0.1, 25.1.0 etc.

This is how the inside of folder 25.1.0 looks like:
[image: This is how the inside of folder 25.1.0 looks like]

when I try to import the 25.1.0 folder into eclipse it says "Select a directory to search for existing Android projects"

How can I fix this?

Comment: you should not be using eclipse in first place. its deprecated. use android studio instead.

Comment: The Android Plugin for Eclipse is no longer supported. Please switch to Android Studio instead.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio now is official IDE for android development provided by Google. The Android plugin for Eclipse doesn't have support anymore. Eclipse is setting up Andmore project: https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore to try to continue work on allowing Eclipse to build Android apps. But you are strongly encouraged to use Android Studio instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with this problem too and solved by getting appcompat-v7 from [here](https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-v7-appcompat).
I know you should use Eclipse for now and I highly recommend these repositories which are very useful for eclipse now.

Finally I also suggest to turn to Android Studio asap.