# troubles importing appcompat v4 and v7

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library

I´m having a lot of troubles to import the compat jars or project in eclipse, I know that there´s a lot of Questions about this tip, but I´ve been searching a lot of hours and nothing...

I want to check the permissions of my app.

This i what do i have in the folder
 `C:\sdk-android\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\23.3.0`

[image]

If I import(coping or as an External jar) `appcompat-v7-23.3.0-sources.jar`  gives me errors `The import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity cannot be resolved`

I have updated all, SDK Manager and all elements in it.
Same trouble with v4 version...
I had readed that another option is to`appcompat_v7 project` but i cant find it on my computer...

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Why are you using eclipse?

Comment: It´s only for this project, all the rest is in Android Studio

Comment: `appcompat-v7-23.3.0-sources.jar` is just sources, you need to import `appcompat-v7-23.3.0.aar`, but I don't know how to use aar in eclipse. You will have to find it out by yourself.

Comment: You just create a project for appcompat-v7 and build the library, then link to it. It is a library with **resources** so you cannot just copy over the jar. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878803/how-to-add-android-support-v7-libraries-in-eclipse) is how to do it in minute detail.

Comment: i´ve tried, but the jar isnt working prperly...

Comment: If some one could pass me the appcompat v4 23.0.jar and appcompat v7 23.0.jar will save me

Comment: It's **not** a case of **just copying jars**, there are **resources** that you need to compile into your project (from the library project), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998368/the-import-android-support-v7-cannot-be-resolved). **NOTE(1)** v7 contains v4, don't compile both, they **will conflict. (2)** Library project must to **open** with your application project to work.