# Create New Android Project In Eclipse Fails

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

When I want to create a new project in eclipse it gives me this error every time.

[image: Creating new project]

[image: Errors]

[image]

I have installed ADT using Eclipse->Help->Install New Software.

[image: ADT]

I have installed sdk and jdk and.

[image]

What is problem? it really gets me sick. I will throw my computer away.

Comment: the problem is you are still using eclipse which is no longer officially supported

Comment: What should I do? I have bought a book and it is using eclipse too. for android 5

Comment: First return that book because if its telling you to use that its not a good book. Then download Android Studio

Comment: Android Studio? There is something named Gradle in that which is not supported in my country. I have many problems with Android Studio. Is there a book to learn Android Studio?

Comment: I'm also having this problem. I don't want to use Android Studio because my laptop doesn't run it well, and I'm intensely familiar with Eclipse. Don't cave in imho.

Comment: I used to work with Eclipse before. why it is happening now?

Comment: Just forget Eclipse. Android Studio is the main tool developed by Google for developing to Android. Eclipse is not longer supported. Android Studio has a lot of powerful tools that Eclipse don't have. You will be grateful in the long run.

Comment: There is no resource to learn android studio unfortunately. All the android learning books are using Eclipse to develop android apps.

Comment: @Ali.Rashidi you can learn the basics of android studio here http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html

Comment: You only write code in Eclipse/Android Studio, so learning Android coding should not matter which IDE you use. There is still File>New>Project in Android Studio

Comment: @tyczj Unfortunately it is not available in IRAN.

Comment: @cricket_007 Codes are the same you mean?

Comment: Yes, it is only Java

Comment: The real problem, though, is that Eclipse doesn't import the appropriate support libraries that you need and that's why you see the error. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21229781/2308683) for details on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the nightly build of Andmore (unofficial Android dev tools, you may be using it, but not nightly perhaps). I can't tell you if that works or not, but they did update the support libraries. Add this to your update sites: http://download.eclipse.org/andmore/nightly. Also make sure to go onto your Problems tab and delete all (not sure if Andmore clears them) then clean projects in menu.

Answer (score 0):

U have to add appcompat library in your project. If u want to use appcompat.