# Maven package with source and attached dependecies

Tags: java, maven

I'm having a hard time adding java source files and the attached dependencies to an output jar file using maven.

What I want to archive is having the compiled classes, the source files and all dependencies (without sources) in one jar which can be distributed.

```
- com/name/project/*.class
- com/name/project/*.java
- lib/*.jar
- META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Here is the pom.xml what I have so far:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.name.project/main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I hope anyone can help me.

cheers
dan

Comment: Let me say in short. Wrong way. Use the usual Maven ways which supports already having a source, javadoc package etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided not to add the dependecy-jars to my output jar. Instead I used the following pom.xml to include my sources to the jar alongside with the compiled dependencies.
I had to exclude the **/*.java files due to some strange dependencies having the sources included as well.

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        <excludes>**\/*.java</excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

thanks for the help.

cheers
dan

Answer (score 1):

A JAR usually really shouldn't contain other JARs, but of course there's nothing to prevent you from doing that.

You can include the source code neatly using the `resource` section as follows:

```
<build>
    </resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
```

I'd venture a guess that you might be able to bind your `copy-dependencies` task to the `resources` phase and see if that would include the dependency JARs in the final artifact.

Comment: yes, currently the dependencies will just be copied to the target/lib/ directory, but not included in the jar file.

Comment: I've updated my answer - try binding `copy-dependencies` to the `resources` phase.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037188/how-to-configure-eclipse-build-path-to-use-maven-dependencies). Just check you have correctly configured your maven+IDE co-operation