# Use AsyncHttpClient in a Java Project with Maven

Tags: java, maven, asynchttpclient

I'm creating a java project using Maven in Eclipse. I have to use the library **AsyncHttpClient** ([https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client](http://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client)). I've already entered in the file pom.xml dependency for this library. I need the class UriComponents present in the package org.asynchttpclient.uri but I can not import it. I did:

```
import org.asynchttpclient.uri.UriComponents;
```

But I get an error.

This is the link of the class that I need:

[UriComponents.java](http://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/asynchttpclient/uri/UriComponents.java)

How can I import it? Thanks.

Here is my current pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<project xmlns="maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"; 
         xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";        
         xsi:schemaLocation="maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">; 
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
...
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.ning</groupId> 
    <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId> 
    <version>1.8.12</version> 
</dependency>
...
```

Comment: Could you post your pom.xml, or at least the relevant part?

Comment: Sure.Here:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

...

<dependency>
 <groupId>com.ning</groupId>
 <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
 <version>1.8.12</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Maybe. Unfortunately I am new to stackoverflow so I can not paste images. I had already tried :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's available in version `1.9.0-BETA6` under `com.ning.http.client.uri.UriComponents`

The one you are requesting seems to be in the master branch, and not being released yet.

Check the forum at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/asynchttpclient

Answer (score 0):

See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037188/how-to-configure-eclipse-build-path-to-use-maven-dependencies)

`"If you right-click on your project, there should be an option under "maven" to "enable dependency management". That's it."`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The procedure shown in that post I had already done. I have already added the dependency for AsyncHttpClient. My problem is that I can not import the package org.asynchttpclient.uri that is part of the library AsyncHttpClient. (sorry for my english)