# Maven not on project's build path in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, maven

Please, I recently created a "Maven Project" under Eclipse Luna (Ctrl+N > Maven Project), but maven was not found on my project's build path and the Maven folder was not also found in my project. As a result I couldn't use javax.ws.rs.Path. I have tried all the solutions given in this link:[How to configure Eclipse build path to use Maven dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037188/how-to-configure-eclipse-build-path-to-use-maven-dependencies)

but to no avail. Does anyone has similar issue?

**Environment**

Eclipse Luna

JRE 1.7

Mac OS 10.9.5

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your Eclipse > Windows > Preferences > Maven > Installations correctly configured? I hope you also have a JDK installed and not only the JRE :)

Comment: Yeah. it is configured :)

Comment: What do you mean by "the Maven folder was not also found in my project", can you post a picture of the created Maven project or provide further details about the error you are getting?

Comment: @A.DiMatteo from the images added, you can see Maven folder is not shown on the project as the Apache Tomcat and JRE System Library.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let's be sure Maven is correctly installed in your machine.
Basically, check from any command line if everything is correct, simply running: `mvn -version`

You can firstly try to build your project from command line, getting to the folder containing the project and opening a command line to it.

Once you are from the command line in your maven project, then you can run:

```
mvn clean install
```

Then let's also make sure everything is correctly set-up in Eclipse.

- From Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations, check whether it point to the installation you just verified above
- I also suggest, once in the Maven Eclipse settings, to go to User Interface > check option "Open XML page in the POM editor by default"

If everything is fine, then make sure to also run right click on the project > Maven > Update projects.. to be sure Eclipse and Maven are in synch concerning dependencies and settings.

If you are still encountering issues, you could then:

- Right click on the project > Maven > Disable Maven Nature, then right click on the project > Configure > Convert to Maven Project
- Alternatively, from the command line, run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, then refresh the project on Eclipse

Comment: Oh man. I now know the reason because or your instructions. i followed your instructions and realized, for the first time, that Maven is not even installed anymore on my machine. I guess during an OS update, it was taken out or something. Afew digging on google revealed that Maven is not installed any more by default on Mac OS X 10.9. So, I had to  install it myself using brew install maven. Thanks man.